# Comparing SKU numbers

Tags: java

Sonar complains that I have too many `return` statements. How can I reduce the `return` statement count nicely?

```
public int compare(Sku o1, Sku o2) {
    if (o1 == null) {
        return (o2 == null) ? 0 : 1;
    } else if (o2 == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (o1.getSkuNumber() == null) {
        return o2.getSkuNumber() == null ? 0 : 1;
    } else if (o2.getSkuNumber() == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    return o1.getSkuNumber().compareTo(o2.getSkuNumber());
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Since you state that you're using Java 8, you should use the variety of new `Comparator` static methods to extract the relevant fields for comparison:

```
public int compare(Sku o1, Sku o2) {
    Comparator<Sku> c1 = Comparator.nullsLast(null);
    return c1.thenComparing(Sku::getSkuNumber,
            Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())).compare(o1, o2);
}
```

1. When [`Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) is given a `null` argument, it considers two non-`null` argument to be equal. This is the basis of our first comparator.
2. We then need to compare by `getSkuNumber()`, so we pass the [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `Sku::getSkuNumber` to [`Comparator.thenComparing(Function, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) as our second comparator. However, since SKU numbers may be `null`, we use a nested (or tertiary?) `null`-friendly comparator, `Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator)` again, as the second argument. The final comparator in use is just [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--), which performs the final straightforward integer comparison if both SKU numbers are non-`null`.

**edit:** [@Simon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104313/how-to-avoid-too-many-method-return-statements#comment190785_104360) mentioned a good point that since your existing `compare(Sku, Sku)` method is likely to be the *implementation* for implementing `Comparable<Sku>`, you should consider making the `Comparator` I suggested above a `public static final` field, so that it doesn't have to be created every time, e.g.:

```
public static final Comparator<Sku> COMPARATOR = 
                        Comparator.nullsLast((Comparator<Sku>) null)
                            .thenComparing(Sku::getSkuNumber,
                                Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Comment: Note that the `public int compare(Sku o1, Sku o2)` method in itself is likely from a `Comparator<Sku>` implementation, so this `Comparator` thing that you create here should be made a `public static final` and used instead of the existing. Or it should at least be stored in a variable so that the comparator does not need to be created every time

Comment: @SimonForsberg thanks for the suggested, have updated my answer. :)

Comment: It is shorter, but not really readable

Answer (score 4):

You are specifically asking about how to reduce the number of return statements, where one answer suggest a total rewrite, which most likely is a good option. However to tackle the general question of reducing the number of the return statements here are some ideas to play with:

- Group similar returns using mulitple `if` conditions, or simplified tests
- Store return result, before returning once at end
- If possible, do a few early returns to avoid lots of testing and 'difficult' returns later on

Here is a modified variant where I simplified the tests using the simple fact that for the comparison you seem to consider `o1 == null` *equal* to `o1.getSkuNumber() == null`, and I test the `getSkuNumber()` only once, instead of multiple times. If `getSkuNumber()` was expensive, it also does make sense to avoid doing it multiple times.

```
public int compare(Sku o1, Sku o2) {
    // Simplify into two variables to use when testing 
    Comparable o1num = o1 != null ? o1.getSkuNumber() : null;
    Comparable o2num = o2 != null ? o2.getSkuNumber() : null;
    Integer result = null;

    // Simplified test, with storage of return result
    if ( o1num == null && o2num == null) {
      result = 0;

    } else if (o1num == null && o2num != null) {
      result = 1;

    } else if (o1num != null && o2num == null) {
      result = -1;
    }

    // If return result is already set, return it, else
    // do the actual comparison
    return (result != null) ? result : o1num.compareTo(o2num);
}
```

Whether it is worth it for such a simple case, is a matter of taste, but at least the trick to simplify the `o1` vs `o1.getSkuNumber()` is a neat trick, and my first code example is a little gentler to my eye.

You could also opt for a not so readable, but shorter solution like:

```
public int compare(Sku o1, Sku o2) {
    // Simplify into two variables to use when testing 
    Comparable o1num = o1 != null ? o1.getSkuNumber() : null;
    Comparable o2num = o2 != null ? o2.getSkuNumber() : null;

    // Early return if either (or both) is null
    if ( o1num == null || o2num == null) {
      return o1num == null ? (o2num == null ? 0 : 1) :  -1 ;
    } 

    // Do the actual comparison
    return o1num.compareTo(o2num);
}
```

This last one simplifies the `if` structure by realising that all of the `if`'s depend either one or both being null. Then if both are null return `0`, or if only one return `1` or `-1` depending which one is null. The second return statement, does the ordinary comparison as both are not null.

**Edit:** Changed into `Comparable` as it turns out that `getSkuNumber()` can return not only `String`. Further reduced the shortest solution, as suggested in comments, but kept an (unnecessary) level of parenthesis to keep some readability. :-)

Comment: We don't know what's the type of `getSkuNumber()`, it can well be `Integer`, `Long` or a custom `PositiveNumberWithDashes`. ;) Also, the `// Early return` of your final suggestion can be slightly simplified further: `return o2num == null ? o1num == null ? 0 : -1 : 1`. When the `if`-condition is `true`, we just need to check if it's the second condition (`o2num == null`) that 'brings us' into the `return` statement. If that is the case, then we perform another 'check back' on the `null`-ness of `o1num1` to determine which of the three values to return. ;)

Comment: You are correct that it can be further reduced, but then it is really hard to read, I think.